# JPA2 CreateQuery SQL Server Dialect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, substring

The function CreateQuery(string) in java.persistence.Query is returning a different query from what I requested.

My input string to the function is:

> from Underlying where  (SUBSTRING(ticker, (charindex('.', ticker) +
>   1), (len(ticker) - charindex('.', ticker))) in (:exchanges) order by
>   ticker

When I call getResultList() on the Query, I see the following sql in my log:

> Hibernate: select underlying0_.id as id63_, underlying0_.updated_date
>   as updated2_63_, underlying0_.updated_user as updated3_63_,
>   underlying0_.version as version63_, underlying0_.adr as adr63_,
>   underlying0_.desk as desk63_, underlying0_.enabled as enabled63_,
>   underlying0_.forward_start_enabled as forward8_63_,
>   underlying0_.ticker as ticker63_, underlying0_.vol_shift_type as
>   vol10_63_ from underlyings underlying0_ where
>   (substring(underlying0_.ticker, charindex('.', underlying0_.ticker)+1)
>   in (?)) order by underlying0_.ticker

This is query is not a valid SQL Server 2008 query and as expected, I received an error:

> SQL Error: 174, SQLState: S0001 
>   The substring function requires 3 argument(s).

Any one know what is going on here?

FYI, I have tried the following two dialects 1) org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect, and 2) org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

Comment: Can you try LENGTH(ticker) instead of len(ticker).

Comment: Thanks for the respons Gayathri, I tried replacing LEN with LENGTH, however, I get the same result i.e. 3 args in my input gets converted to 2 args as see in the log entry.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks again Gayathri, much apreciated! That was not the issue either. I found the problem, will provide answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it! I ran same query on Oracle with Locate() instead of charindex which worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with function charindex. It is not available in the dialect, therefore causes incorrect mapping. Changing this to the HQL function "locate" (keeping args constant) fixed the issue. My query now works in SQL Server 2008:

> ...where (substring(underlying0_.ticker, charindex('.',
>   underlying0_.ticker)+1, len(underlying0_.ticker)-charindex('.',
>   underlying0_.ticker)) in (?))...

Answer (score -1):

Error clearly mention that `SUBSTRING()` function require 3 Arguments you are passing 2. thus error is in your query.

read about [SUBSTRING()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) Function

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the issue is 1 arg is missing. That is not my question. I am asking about the Dialect which converts a string to a database specific query (in this case, SQL Server 2008). My input string clearly has 3 args, it then gets converted to having 2 args. Thanks anyways.